# Removing "double" borders between AG Grid rows and scrolling the grid acts unintuitive

Tags: css, border, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm customizing AG Grid using CSS. I have a goal to eliminate "double" borders between two rows (where there is no total-row class included) so the borders look like they're the same width everywhere.

I have this setting in my CSS file:

```
.ag-row:not(.total-row) + .ag-row:not(.total-row) {
    border-top: none;
}
```

And it's working fine when the page is loaded but right away when I start scrolling the grid (vertically), *some* of the border-top removals are working and some are not and it seems like it's very coincidental. It varies which top borders are removed and which are not when I keep scrolling back and forth.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Please could you provide a stackblitz that demonstrates the issue?